# How to pass dynamic value in excel file that is created using suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have created an excel file in suitelet. I want to pass dynamic value in the excel file so How can i do that. For Eg: 
I want to pass :

```
  var transaction_id = searchresult.getValue("internalid",'transaction');
```

in the excel File.

I tried the below method but its throwing Corrupted file error. *Note : File with static data is generated fine problem while passing the dynamic data to the file.

```
  var xmlStr = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>';
    xmlStr += '<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ';
    xmlStr += 'xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" ';
    xmlStr += 'xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" ';
    xmlStr += 'xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ';
    xmlStr += 'xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">';

    xmlStr += '<Worksheet ss:Name='sheet_name'>';

    //Below mention is the place(transaction_id) where I want to pass the dynamic value 
    xmlStr += '<Table>' +
    '<Row>' +
    '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">transaction_id</Data></Cell>' +
    '</Row>';

xmlStr += '</Table></Worksheet></Workbook>';

var xlsFile = nlapiCreateFile('sheet_name.xls', 'EXCEL', nlapiEncrypt(xmlStr, 'base64'));

xlsFile.setFolder(6157);

var fileID = nlapiSubmitFile(xlsFile);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you already have `transaction_id` as a variable, and you've populated it appropriately, you'll just need to concatenate the two tag strings with your variable:

```js
'<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">' + transaction_id + '</Data></Cell>' +
```